# Django 'str' object is not callable when deleting a foreign key object

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have a model with a foreign key to another model and when I try to delete an object (in this example the object with id=0 that exists).

> ### Models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    example = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel,related_name='example',on_delete=models.SET_NULL    ,blank=True,null=True)

class OtherModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

**shell**

```
>>> import project
>>> from project import models
>>> project.models.OtherModel.objects.get(id=0).delete()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "console", line 1, in "module"
File ".../lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py"
, line 890, in delete collector.collect([self], keep_parents=keep_parents)
File ".../lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 222, in collect
field.remote_field.on_delete(self, field, sub_objs, self.using)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Given the two models are in the same file, the above never works, since you refer to a class that is at that moment not yet defined.

Comment: What does `print(project.models.OtherModel.objects.get(id=0))` tell you?

Comment: Shouldn't be id=1? Django ORM starts pk from 1

Comment: Curious... what does `MyModel._meta.get_field('example').remote_field.on_delete` return and, if it is not a function, what type is the return?

Comment: Hi, I found my error, in another Model someone wrote on_delete options in quotes, and this is considered 'str'. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create Foreign Key relation with a model which is not defined yet.

`example = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel,related_name='example',on_delete=models.SET_NULL    ,blank=True,null=True)`

Here Other model is defined below this Line, so it can't identify what OtherModel is.

Comment: Hi, I found my error, in another Model someone wrote on_delete options in quotes, and this is considered 'str'. Thank you!